# Clean up a CSV file

Tags: batch-file

I use a `.bat` file to move a CSV that is created every day.  I now need to clean it up:

- find and replace "-" to 0
- find and replace empty cells with 0
- remove all spaces

The CSV is only 20 lines.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/02/08/how-can-i-find-and-replace-text-in-a-text-file.aspx  - probably the easiest way.

Comment: Some sample data would be of immense assistance. You need to show the before and after form. As it stands, you're asking just how long is a piece of string?

Answer (score 2):

Don't really know, what you need. Please explain more, if this doesn'w work for you:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (old.csv) do (
  set "line=%%a"
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  set "line=!line: =!"
  set "line=!line:-=0!"
  >> new.csv echo(!line!
  endlocal
)
```

Comment: `set "line=!line:,,=,0,!"`  I think he wants that change too,

Comment: @foxidrive Won't work correctly with 2 or more ajacent empty fields in a row. Also won't work for leading/trailing empty fields.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers Yes, it isn't very useful.  On three adjacent fields it skipped the second one, as well as leading and trailing ones.

Comment: Thanks for the help had a typo creating problems all sorted

Answer (score 0):

Batch files are not a good tool for this. You'd be far better off using PowerShell:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\path\to\in.csv') `
  -replace ' ', '' `
  -replace '-', '0' `
  -replace '^,', '0,' `
  -replace ',$', ',0' `
| % {
  while ($_ -match ',,') { $_ = $_ -replace ',,', ',0,' }
  $_
} | Out-File 'C:\path\to\out.csv'
```

or even VBScript:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

inFilename  = "C:\path\to\in.csv"
outFilename = "C:\path\to\out.csv"

Set inFile  = fso.OpenTextFile(inFilename)
Set outFile = fso.OpenTextFile(outFilename, 2, True)

outFile.WriteLine inFile.ReadLine  'write header
Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream
  line = inFile.ReadLine

  line = Replace(line, " ", "")
  line = Replace(line, "-", "0")
  If Left(line, 1) = "," Then line = "0" & line
  If Right(line, 1) = "," Then line = line & "0"
  Do While InStr(line, ",,") > 0
    line = Replace(line, ",,", ",0,")
  Loop

  outFile.WriteLine line
Loop

inFile.Close
outFile.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (yourfile.csv) DO (
 SET "line=%%i"&CALL :process
)
)>newcsv.csv
GOTO :EOF

:process
SET line=%line: =%
SET line=%line:-=0%
SET line2=%line%
SET line=%line:,,=,0,%
IF NOT "%line%"=="%line2%" GOTO process
IF "%line:~0,1%"=="," SET line=0%line%
ECHO %line%
GOTO :EOF
```

Now the interweb fairies are finally back on board, here's my version...

Comment: I have tried this code and the code answer.  The result I am getting is a Coloumn of = signs for both.  So I may be doing somthing incorrect or explained it poorly.                                                             I have a csv file eg ID,-,C   ,                                                     and I would like to change it to ID,C,0,198,mm,

Comment: Sorry I hit enter before finishing eg -,IM   ,,198,0, to 0,IM,0,198,0,                                                       Below is the code I have typed in                                                                  @ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (recon_S21206.csv) DO (
 SET "line = %%i"&CALL :PROCESS
)
)>new.csv
GOTO :EOF

:process
set line=%line: =%
set line=%line: -=0%
set line2=%line:,,=,0,!"
IF NOT "%line%"=="%line2%" GOTO process
IF "%line:~0,1%"=="," SET line=0%line%
ECHO %line%
GOTO :%EOF